# Windows 7 Logoff script

Tags: windows, scripting, registry, logoff

I need to add log off script on windows. I can do it through gpedit.msc, but i need to automate it via scripts.

I find lot of registry keys examples, but no one works.

E.g : http://www.jhouseconsulting.com/2008/08/26/scripting-updates-to-the-gptini-for-the-local-group-policy-39
Or https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5c0d7e87-6dec-4f87-8ef2-f43b4064d4d5/execution-of-a-script-at-every-logoff-of-any-user?forum=w7itprosecurity

No one works.

Do you have any solutions, which is tested and works for you?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use GPEDIT for creation of those entries it creates the policy in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Logoff
```

as it is explained in one of your links. However when I try this there are a lot more entries created than the few described in the technet thread, so the first thing to do is, create the entry manually, go there, export everything and re-import on another computer.

If this doesn't work I would scrap the whole registry idea and realize it via the task scheduler. Create a task with a trigger on the logoff event of any user in the gui (might need to enable additional auditing depending on which events you really need), export it to xml and re-import it using

```
schtasks /Create /XML <xmlfile> /TN <taskname>
```

Comment: As i write in first line, i need it to AUTOMATE VIA SCRIPTS. Going to gpedit.msc and click on ... This is not automatable via scripts.

Comment: sorry I misinterpreted the "I can do it via gpedit part" I rephrased the answer but imo especially the very first link you posted is a very detailed script so if that doesn't work I am not sure it is really easy

Comment: Thanks. Basically yes, i have done it by scheduler task. Trigger is event 4647 (log off event) on Protokol Security. It works :)